# $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \text{arctanh}(\sin x) \text{arctan}(a \tan(x)) \cos(x) \ dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

Are you kind to let me know the way? By the way, don't you have a "curiosity" tag?
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \text{arctanh}(\sin x) \text{arctan}(a \tan(x)) \cos(x) \ dx, \quad a>0$$

Comment: Which problem led you to get this integral?

Comment: What would be the point of a curiosity tag? Tags have a purpose, specifically, to let people find things that interest them or which they can answer. What tickles your curiosity, on the other hand, is highly subjective.

Comment: I suggest this is discussed on meta if it's of further interest (:

Comment: It's $\mathrm{artanh}$ as in *area tangentis hyperbolici*, no arc here ...

Comment: @martini are you referring to my post? In this case I think you're joking ...

Comment: @Crazy_girl No, I'm not joking. It's $\arctan$, but $\mathrm{artanh}$.

Comment: @martini http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arctanh.html

Comment: It seems it is a "more proper" way of writing it. Much like you can use sine and sinus interchangeably. Although in this case, I have to agree with martini that using arc is inherently wrong.

Answer (score 13):

$$\forall a>0,\quad\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\text{artanh}(\sin x)\,\arctan(a\,\tan(x))\cos(x)\ dx=\\\frac\pi2\Re\left(\ln\left(2\,a^{-1}+2\right)-\frac{\ln\left(2\sqrt{a^{-4}-a^{-2}}+2\,a^{-2}-1\right)}{2 \sqrt{1-a^2}}\right),$$
where $\Re$ denotes the [real part](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RealPart.html).

Comment: I still need to rigorously justify some steps of the proof, so I leave this result as a conjecture for now.